# Evaluate $\displaystyle\int e^{-x^2}\ dx$

Tags: real-analysis

I got a lot of trouble with evaluating
$$\int e^{-x^2}\ dx$$
I could eventually integrate the Taylor polynomial of the function, but it is not what is required.
Could anyone here help me out? Thank you for any answer.

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle\int a^{x^n}dx$ does not possess a [closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) expression; it cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, unless, of course, either *a* or *n* is $0$ or $1$. See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to express the andiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$ in closed form using standard functions. However, this function is important enough that it gets its own name, the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), as a special function.